# How to close multiple tasks in taskwarrior?

Tags: taskwarrior

I forgot to do a recurring task and I now have it 10 times in my task list. Is there a way to close the task for instance: task range ids 10-25 done
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete tasks 10 to 25:

```
task 10-25 done
```